# In the SageMaker SDK Is there any way to combine / interpolate a ParameterString in a ProcessingInput/Processor/ProcessingStep?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When using the [SageMaker SDK](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), I would like to use a pipeline parameter [`ParameterString`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#sagemaker.workflow.parameters.ParameterString) to construct a S3 path, thus I need to interpolate the `ParameterString` somehow, python `str.format()` and f-strings do not properly work with `ParameterString`.

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

date_parameter = ParameterString(name="date")
p_input = ProcessingInput(
  source=f"s3://my-bucket/date={date_parameter}",
  destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),)
```

What can be used to compose / combine / interpolate pipeline parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent to string interpolation that you can use in a SageMaker Pipeline is [`sagemaker.workflow.functions.Join`](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/workflows/pipelines/sagemaker.workflow.pipelines.html#sagemaker.workflow.functions.Join)

```
from sagemaker.workflow.execution_variables import ExecutionVariables
from sagemaker.workflow.functions import Join
from sagemaker.workflow.parameters import ParameterString

date_parameter = ParameterString(name="date")
source_variable = Join(on='', values=['s3://bucket-name/date=', date_parameter])

p_input = ProcessingInput(
  input_name="xxx",
  source=source_variable,
  destination="/opt/ml/processing/input",
)
```

The `source_variable` in the code above will translate to `{'Std:Join': {'On': '', 'Values': ['s3://bucket-name/date=', {'Get': 'Parameters.date'}]}}` on the [CreatePipeline > PipelineDefinition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreatePipeline.html#API_CreatePipeline_RequestSyntax) pipeline definition.

And when the SageMaker Pipeline is actually started that will be evaluated by SageMaker to a literal string